# Power set functors preserve monicness

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

[This](http://sun.iwu.edu/~lstout/theoremlist/node12.html) link discusses power set functors.

> **Proposition 5.7** If $f$ is a epimorphism then so is $\exists_f$.
>
> **Proposition 5.8** If $f$ is an monomorphism then so is $\forall_f$.

A little confused...doesn't proposition 5.8 apply to $\exists_f$ also? Certainly if $f$ is injective then $f^* \circ \exists_f = \text{Id}$, so $\exists_f$ must be injective.

Am I missing that they're talking about a richer category than just $\mathsf{Set}$? Maybe because of additional structure monic means more than just being injective here?

Answer (score 1):

Note the language at the [top directory](http://sun.iwu.edu/~lstout/theoremlist/theoremlist.html):

> In these notes the general instructions are to prove or disprove and salvage if possible each of the Propositions and Theorems. Use the definitions as given.

I have no direct experience thinking of power set functions in this context, so I'm not sure what 'results' are actually true.

Digging in more specifically, the language

> **Proposition 5.2**$\;$ $f^*: \mathcal{P}(B) \to \mathcal P(A)$ is a functor; that is, if $B'' \subseteq B'$, then $f^*(B'') \subseteq f^*(B')$.

suggests that here a functor should preserve containment. So, I think what we have here are "categorified posets" (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91377/the-category-of-posets)); that is, given a set $S$, its powerset $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is the category whose objects are subsets of $S$. For $s', s'' \in \mathcal{P}(S)$ we have a morphism $s' \to s''$, if and only if $s' \subseteq s''$.

Viewed in this context, it is indeed asking you to show that $f^*$ preserves morphisms; that is, $B' \to B''$ implies $f^*(B') \to f^*(B'')$.

I'm not absolutely sure of this, but it seems to be the most sensible way to speak of functions between power sets as functors.

Comment: I think you answered something that was not asked in the original question..

Comment: That's quite possible. I tried to focus on "Am I missing that they're talking about a richer category than just $\mathsf{Set}$?". My answer to that question is "It seems that they're asking you to look at poset categories, rather than $\mathsf{Set}$".